# Get temporary table from SQL Server with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

in Python 3 sqlalchemy I do the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(odbc_string)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute("""exec my_database..my_procedure;""")
    cursor = conn.execute("""select * from #result;""")
_df = cursor.fetchall()
```

The procedure "my_procedure" does the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @mean int = 0, 
    @std int = 1
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @mean as mean, @std as std into #result;
    UPDATE #result set mean = 10;
END
GO
```

For some reason, the Python code results in an error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) [SQL Server]Invalid object name '#result'

Could somebody help me with this error?

Comment: I think it is because of Scope of the temp table, Try Executing and Getting the value in same query.

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran My bad. I did not mention that the procedure does several updates and inserts into the #result table. In the end I receive the error :
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

Comment: I think you are receiving the error from this Statement, cursor = conn.execute("""select * from #result;"""). If the execution is done in a different session then table would not be available and it will throw a error.

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran I checked it with this:

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(odbc_string)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute("""select 1 as one into #result; update #result set one = 10;""")
    cursor = conn.execute("""select * from #result;""")
_df = cursor.fetchall()

And it worked.